# Error en la ejecución de la programación (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

En la ejecución de este ejercicio tengo problemas. No he incluido el botón de la llamada en el mensaje pero sí que lo he añadido en el programa.
El enunciado es el siguiente: "Cread una función que calcule la media de varios números introducidos, donde estos pueden ser un número variable de valores." 
Para añadirle dificultad también he hecho que sean un numero variable de variables. Me genera un numero de variables al azar correctamente. Lo he hecho entre 1 y el 10 variables para resumirlo.
Se pueden introducir los datos correctamente pero posteriormente, una vez he terminado de introducir los datos, no me sale la pantalla de alert(resultado). Lo he probado con document.write(resultado) y tampoco funciona.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function media(){
        var variable=0;
        var resultado;
        var x;
        min=1;
        max=10;
        var numeroale=Math.floor(Math.random()*max-min+1)+min;
        for( var intento=0;;intento=intento+1){
            if (intento<numeroale){
                x=window.prompt("Introduzca un numero:");
                variable=variable+parseInt(x);
            }else if(intento==numeroale){
                resultado=num.toString(variable/(intento+1));

            }   
        }
        return(resultado);
        alert(resultado);
    }
</script>
```

Y ya que estoy formularé otra pregunta (relacionado con el tema) a la siguiente duda que me surgió el otro día. Me comentaron que no es recomendable cortar un "for" con un "break" o un "continue", que otro método hay o como podría hacerlo?

Saludos,

Comment: Tienes la línea `}else if(numero==numeroale){` pero `numero` no existe.

Comment: Cierto pero lo he cambiado y sucede lo mismo @KroneauxSchneider

Comment: Tienes un `return`  dentro del `for`, eso sale de la función no del `for`

Comment: Seria interesante saber porque te dijeron que no es recomendable usar `break;` para cortar un  bucle. Dicho sea de paso `continue` no corta el bucle, solo hace que vuelva inmediatamente, para continuar la iteración en el próximo valor.

Comment: @Klaimmore si es esto a lo que te refieres sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @Marcos  "El uso de la sentencia break para interrupir un bucle NO es aconsejado, al igual que el uso de la sentencia continue. Por tanto, deberías pensar como definir..." Y lo de continue lo se, simplemente era para resumir. Exactamente no se porque pero dicen que no es aconsejable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes los siguientes problemas:

- Debes indicar cuando parar el `for`, ya que actualmente no lo estas haciendo o hacer un `break;`. De lo contrario puedes generar un bucle infinito. Esto no ocurre porque cuando entra a `if(intento==numeroale)`, la variable `num` no esta definida.
- Todo lo que esta posterior a un `return` nunca sera ejecutado.

### Solución:

```js
function media() {
  var variable = 0;
  var resultado;
  var x;
  min = 1;
  max = 10;
  var numeroale = Math.floor(Math.random() * max - min + 1) + min;
  // AQUI indicamos que el for debe parar cuando `intento` sea igual a `numeroale`
  for (var intento = 0; intento < numeroale; intento = intento + 1) {
    x = window.prompt("Introduzca un numero:");
    variable = variable + parseInt(x);
  }
  // AQUI calculamos el resultado
  resultado = variable / intento;
  // AQUI ejecutamos el `alert` antes del `return`
  alert(resultado);
  return resultado;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="media()">Empezar</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Se me ha solucionado el problema ;)